# How to add a folder to the "Quick Access" section in windows 10? OR How to call windows explorer context menu option for a folder?

Tags: c#, windows-10

I have been trying to find a way to add a folder to user's quick access section in windows 10.

The code I have working with Windows 7 and 8 doesn't work in windows 10 because apparently the favorites section has been changed.

Please either suggest how to add a folder to that section or call the context menu option "Pin to quick access" from windows explorer context menu. 
P.S. I have already used `runme.exe`. It does work but it is commercially distributable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add a folder to quick access section by calling the right click context menu for the folder.

I used and exe file for this purpose which I downloaded from this link:

[Reference link](http://www.maddogsw.com/cmdutils/)

I used Context.exe from the package for my purpose.